# Adjust UIView width when other views increase or decrease in size

Tags: ios, uiview, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a UIView with a side menu that comes from the left and pushes the right view from full with to a smaller size (full width - (menu width)).
Per someones suggestion I accomplish that effect by changing the constant in the constraint for the menu width: from 0 to 200.

The (right side view) UIView that's gonna hold the view that I will load to it has the constraints seen in this image (menu is on the left in blue):

[image: img]

I add the new UIView to the detailsView (container mentioned above) with the following code:

```
var viewNames = NSDictionary.FromObjectsAndKeys (new NSObject[] {
    view.View
}, new NSObject[] {
    new NSString ("detailsView")
});

detailsViewContainer.AddSubview (view.View);

view.View.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
detailsViewContainer.AddConstraints (NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat ("H:|[detailsView]|", 0, new NSDictionary (), viewNames));
```

The problem is that the newly added view always has the full width (1024) when the menu is collapsed but also when the menu is expanded, pushing the view outside the app limits on the right.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Make the master view width constraint (add one if there is no) to be <= 1024 (not strict). I would do the following:

- `|H:|-0-menuView-masterView-0-|`
- and specify in designer the width constraint for masterView as Less or Equal 1024
- and specify in designer the width constraint for menuView as equal to 200. Make an outlet for it and change dynamically in code with
  animation from 200 to 0 and back when required.

where:

- menuView is menu UIView
- masterView is master UIView placeholder

when your menu (green view) is open width constraint will be equal 200:
[image]

as soon as you set constraint to 0 your view will resize the main placeholder (orange view) as well:
[image]

Please find storyboard sample by the following link:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19503836/Main.storyboard

Comment: Thanks for the help @Alexey, but many of your suggestions are already in place. The one missing was the width Less or Equal to 1024. But adding that one didn't solve the problem. Have any other ideas?